Django REST Framework 401 error with valid credentials
I'm having an issue where I send a POST request to an api endpoint restaurant/api-token-auth and I get a 401 error with the json response:
{
    "detail": "Invalid token."
}

This response is appearing even though I'm sending the right credentials in the POST request (username and password). In this case I tried my admin account and it still gives me this response.
This is my code for urls.py (app level):
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('menu/', views.MenuItemView.as_view()),
    path('menu/<int:pk>', views.SingleMenuItemView.as_view()),
    path('api-token-auth/', obtain_auth_token)
    
]
    

urls.py (project level):
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from restaurant.views import BookingViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'tables', BookingViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('restaurant/', include('restaurant.urls')),
    path('restaurant/booking/', include(router.urls)),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
]

settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'restaurant',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'djoser',
]

...(rest of code)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES' : [

        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        

    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : [
        
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        

    ]


}


DJOSER = {"USER_ID_FIELD" : "username"}

I tried manually creating tokens using the admin panel and using the djoser api endpoint auth/token/login and it works but this way it doesn't.

Something seems wrong here :
path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')), path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')), 

Djoser works as far as I can see but DRF for some reason doesn't.

Found the solution, the code is right it's just that I was sending a bearer token with the credentials in the POST request instead of only sending the credentials in Insomnia.
